# Downloading directories WINDOWS

Tags: c++, sockets, directory

I have an application that transfers files via socket, desire that this also make transfers directories.

How can I download a full DIRECTORY via socket?

The program works like this, it asks the user to enter the remote directory where the file is to transfer Example: **C:\users\server\file.dat**

After it makes a validation to confirm the existence of the file,
and finally it transfers byte by byte.

The problem is that when the user type a directory validation fail, an example is if I type **C:\users\SERVER\DIRECTORY**

the program then returns an error FAILED IN READ BYTES

The solution would be to zip the directory, but the server only works with command line "shell", and Windows has nothing to zip by native command line.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read a directory like an ordinary file. You should search for all files yourself and send them one by one. This means you should also send paths to all files and reproduce their hierarchy yourself.